# Could someone please explain how to properly write this Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm looking for someone to show me where I went wrong. The instructions are as follows:

Write the following function (use the songs array to determine what to return).
getSongsNamesByArtist - this function expects a string as an argument
and returns an array containing the names of only those songs in
the songs array whose artist properties are equal to the string
that is passed to it.

So I did this:

```
let songs = [];
function createSong(name, artist) {
    let song = {
        name: name,
        artist: artist
    }
    songs.push(song);

    return song;
}
              
var heroes = new createSong("Heroes", "Bowie");
var jubileeStreet = new createSong("Jubilee Street", "Nick Cave");
var buena = new createSong("Buena", "Morphine");
var changes = new createSong("Changes", "Bowie");
var belaLugosi = new createSong("Bela Lugosi is Dead", "Bauhaus");



// I could get only this far:

function getSongsNamesByArtist(artist) {
  let names = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    let song = songs[i];
    if (song.artist === artist) {
      names.push(song.name);
      return names;
    }
  }
}


console.log(getSongsNamesByArtist("Bowie")) // returns: [ 'Heroes' ], but not both of them.
```

Could you please give me a hint where I went wrong?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing an early return in the if statement. So as soon as you are finding a match you return the result.

```
function getSongsNamesByArtist(artist) {
  let names = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    let song = songs[i];
    if (song.artist === artist) {
      names.push(song.name);
      return names; // <- here is your problem
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, you want to return after the loop.

```
function getSongsNamesByArtist(artist) {
  let names = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    let song = songs[i];
    if (song.artist === artist) {
      names.push(song.name);
    }
  }

  return names; // <- here is where you should return
}
```

You can also consider refactoring this function with the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function in JS

```
function getSongsNamesByArtist(artist) {
  return songs.filter((song) => {
    
    // Filter out the artist you are looking for
    return song.artist === artist;
  }).map((song) => {

    // Reformat your output to only contain the name of the song
    return song.name; 
  });
}
```

Comment: No worries :) @meadow, would you mind marking the answer as solved?

Answer (score 0):

You were returning as soon as first match is found. You have to do it outside for loop . Update your method as below

```js
let songs = [];
function createSong(name, artist) {
    let song = {
        name: name,
        artist: artist
    }
    songs.push(song);

    return song;
}
              
var heroes = new createSong("Heroes", "Bowie");
var jubileeStreet = new createSong("Jubilee Street", "Nick Cave");
var buena = new createSong("Buena", "Morphine");
var changes = new createSong("Changes", "Bowie");
var belaLugosi = new createSong("Bela Lugosi is Dead", "Bauhaus");



// I could get only this far:

function getSongsNamesByArtist(artist) {
  let names = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    let song = songs[i];
    if (song.artist === artist) {
      names.push(song.name);
      
    }
  }
return names;
}


console.log(getSongsNamesByArtist("Bowie"))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: If you are ok with the answer , I hope you will not  mind upvoting and accepting it for better visibility